# What type should my variable be declared as?

Tags: list, c#-4.0

I am new to C# / OOP and am working on converting an existing application into .net 4.0 framework.

My code is as follows:

```
Class abc
        private IList<string[]> GetReportBatchList()
        {
            List<string[]> rowList = new List<string[]>();

            SqlParameter[] prm = { new SqlParameter("@rpt_doc_type_id", SqlDbType.Int, 9) };
            prm[0].Value = 101;

            try
            {
        .....
        .....
        .....
            }

            return rowList;
         }
```

---

```
class xyz

using abc;

       Private Function GenerateReport()
            Try
        {
                Dim rptBatchList As ??????
                rptBatchList = GetReportBatchList()
                While rptBatchList.Read()
        ......
        ......
        ......
        }
        catch
        {
        ......
        }
```

What type should rptBatchList be declared as?

Comment: `private IList<string[]> GetReportBatchList()` sure seems like it has  very, very clear hint in it.  What part of `IList<string[]>` confuses you?

Answer (score 0):

Since the return value of GetReportBatchList() has IList of string as its type, it makes sense that rptBatchList should be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... is this a question about correct return types, or a question about translating C# into VB.Net?

According to the function definition you have, `rptBatchList` will be of type `IList<string[]>` - obviously declared in the correct syntax for VB.Net.

Further to that, because it is a list of string arrays, it doesn't have a Read() function, so maybe you were looking for something that derives from `DbDataReader` instead (like a SqlDataReader)? If you do intend to stick with the current definition then you can use either a `foreach` or a `for` loop to iterate over the list elements, or you can use Linq extensions and use something like this:

```
rptBatchList.ForEach(z => { z.ForEach(x => doSomethingWithThisResultString(x)); } );
```

although that can get messy fast - you probably want to just stick with a couple of nested `foreach` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is VB, but you say you are using C#, so...

For C# it would be `IList<string[]>`.

My VB is a little rusty, but I think it would be `IList(Of String())`.